# Python convert large(10GB) .csv to .tsv

Tags: python, file, csv

New to python. Want to convert the large csv file to tsv.

```
import re
with open("D:/AddressEvaluation/NAD/NAD.csv", 'r') as myfile:
with open("D:/NAD.txt", 'w') as csv_file:
for line in myfile:
  fileContent = re.sub(",", "\t", line)
  csv_file.write(fileContent)
```

Am I missing something? Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: Does it work or not? If not, what happens and how it differs from what you expected? What is the question here?

Comment: This won't work for quotechar fields with commas in them as well.

Comment: Use the stdlib's `csv` module.

Answer (score 9):

This should do it:

```
import csv

with open('D:/AddressEvaluation/NAD/NAD.csv','r') as csvin, open('D:/NAD.txt', 'w') as tsvout:
    csvin = csv.reader(csvin)
    tsvout = csv.writer(tsvout, delimiter='\t')

    for row in csvin:
        tsvout.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Beware of quoting

One difference of CSV and TSV formats is that most implementations of CSV expect that the delimiter *can* be used in the data, and prescribe a mechanism for quoting.
   For example, "Doe, John" would be one column and when converting to TSV you'd need to leave that comma in there but remove the quotes.

```
Name,Age
Bob,12
"Doe, John",13
"William ""Billy"" Bob",14
```

could need to be properly transformed to

```
Name\tAge
Bob\t12
Doe, John\t13
William "Billy" Bob\t14
```

which is not what the proposed code is doing.

You might be better off using a ready-made csv parser, for example the one supplied by pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: yes I am facing that issue of quoting.
Can you please help with the code here.If possible

Comment: @Peteris you don't need Panda, there's already a csv module in the stdlib.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers As far as I recall, the pandas version is faster and for a 10gb file the difference would be noticeable.

Comment: @Peteris Panda's csv reader actually uses the stdlib's csv module, so I don't see how it would be any faster, specially for the such an operation and specially when you definitly DONT want to load the whole 10gb file in memory anyway.